# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'diskStorage')

Tags: undefined, multer

I am new here.

I want to use multer to save files to my server.

```js
import { Router } from "express";
import { multer } from "multer";
import { ffmpeg } from "fluent-ffmpeg";
import { path } from "path";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(
      null,
      "C:Users/ksw/Desktop/back/src/routes/uploads/"
    ); 
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`); 
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if (ext !== ".mp4") {
      return cb(res.status(400).end("only jpg, png, mp4 is allowed"), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file");
```

this is my code.

when I try to run the server, this error shows up.

var storage = _multer.multer.diskStorage({
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'diskStorage')

I thought there was a problem with the storage destination which was relative at first.
The code above contains the absolute path (it was just '/uploads/' before). Neither are correct. (The folder exists)

I can't find similar problems on web. It's probably me missing some basic stuff.
What can I try to solve this issue? Thank you for reading.

Comment: It's my bad that I can't remember exactly how I solved this problem, but if anyone else came here with the same issue, please try to check if ffmpeg is installed properly on your local. I remember downloading 3 ffmpeg related .exe files and restarting my pc.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is kinda too late, but. I had the same problem before and what is helped to me that I just changed style of import. So, you have line:

`import { path } from "path";`

I changed it to `import path = require('path');` (more of express style) and after that it works.